# How to accept an answer if several seem fine?

Tags: discussion

I asked [a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155663/why-does-a-pitcher-with-lemon-juice-have-foam-while-one-with-pure-water-does-no) and got two answers which **seem** to be correct (I am not a chemist / biologist and the answers deal with chemical proprieties of lemons. They both make sense, though and ultimately point to the same physical property).

How can I accept an answer if I do not have the knowledge to decide which on is correct (and there is no clear winner via the upvotes)?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that in the absence of a specialist in lemon juice your question can't be answered. Most of the answers (we can pass mercifully over the one suggesting the bubbles contained methane) point out that wherever there is a foam there is a surface active agent stabilising it. But all the answers can only suggest what that agent might be, and unless someone finds a paper analysing the foam and pinpointing the active ingredient no-one here can say conclusively what it is.

If you're happy with the conclusion that it's due to a surfactant then accept whichever question seems to you to explain things most clearly. If you're unhappy with not knowing exactly what the chmical involved is then accept none of the answers. It may seem untidy to leave a question with no accepted answer, but open questions can and do get answered months or years after they have been posted. You're just waiting for the right person to come along and see the question.